# Dynamic elasticsearch queries

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I've just started using elasticsearch and I'm unsure how you go about using dynamic search queries. Currently I am using something like this:

```
$params['body'] = '
    {
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "' . $terms . '",
                    "fields": [
                    "title^1",
                    "description"
                    ],
                    "minimum_should_match": "70%"
            }
        },
        "highlight": {
            "pre_tags" : ["<b>"],
            "post_tags" : ["</b>"],
            "fields": {
                "description": {
                    "fragment_size": 400
                    },
                    "title": {
                    "number_of_fragments": 0
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }';
```

This works fine when `$terms` is just a string like `ball`. What I'm trying to do is be able for a user to search by string `ball` but maybe they want a ball from a particular location also and would have an optional location check box,if clicked a `$state` could be part of the query now. I looked into [Bool Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)
but I just wasn't sure if this was the right approach. Any guidance would be great.

**Updated code**

```
        {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "description": {
                            "value": "' . $terms .'"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "state_id": {
                        "value": "' . $location . '"
                        }
                    }
                }
                ]
            } 
        }
    }';
```

I'm just using a simple if(isset() in PHP to see if the terms are there and one for the location. If there is no location $_GET variable i'm just setting it as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bool query is one of the best approach for querying more than one query.

```
curl -XPOST "http://192.168.31.16:9200/appviewx/ro/_search" -d'
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
           {
               "term": {
                  "object": {
                     "value": "ball"
                  }
               }
           },
           {
               "term": {
                  "location": {
                     "value": "state"
                  }
               }
           }
        ]
    }
}
}'
```

**Put these in if block**

```
curl -XPOST.      "http://192.168.31.16:9200/appviewx/ro/_search"     -d'
{
 "query": {
"bool": {
    "must": [
       {
           "term": {
              "object": {
                 "value": "ball"
              }
           }
       }
    ]
}
}
```

}'

There are three types in bool.Must,Should,Must_not.

1)Should act as like **OR** condition

2)Must act as like **AND** condition

3)Must_not act as like **NOT** condition

Use filter as much as u can to increase performance. [refer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html)

Comment: Thanks for that help, I almost have it working, I want a user to be able to search by multiple fields. But they are optional, this currently works fine if I search for the `object` (in your example) and `location`. But I want `location` to be optional. Currently, if I don't provide a value for location and only pass a term for `object` I get `Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception`. What is the right way to achieve this would you say? Appreciate the help btw

Comment: Updated my Question, it's in PHP

Comment: Just make a block. If the location field is empty means skip the second part in must. Else construct fully . okay??

Comment: Yeah I understand and will try to implement, wasn't sure whether or not to do that. Thanks